# Initializing/Replacing controller's Controller.Session property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to do an integration test to an action that use the *Controller.Session* property but when I run the solution the value of Session is null.

So I need to initialize/replace it in my integration test.

What is the easiest way (if possible) of doing this?

**Note: I don't wanna use Moq.**

Comment: have you tried https://www.nuget.org/packages/FakeHttpContext ?

Answer (score 0):

The `Session` is only available during an active `HttpContext` , after which is it destroyed. You can only Mock it because there isn't an active `HttpRequest` that will invoke the `Session` in the MVC controller